# Algorithmic/programming approach to Gantt chart problem

Tags: algorithm, gantt-chart

I have 6 processes P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, and P6. I also have their start times and duration given in the problem.

```
process# start duration
1        1     1
2        3     1
3        0     6
4        5     2
5        5     4
6        8     1
```

Now I have to find out the maximum of number of completely non-overlapping processes. Two processes are completely non-overlapping if one does not overlap the other at any point in time.

So I made a Gantt chart and it is easy to see that the answer is 4.
P1, P2, P4 and P6 are completely non-overlapping.
[image: Gantt chart]

Now I have to write a program to compute the same. On a Gantt chart I can easily 'see' the solution.
In the algorithm for my program, I don't know how to minimise the time complexity: currently I'm thinking about taking each process and comparing its start and end times with other processes, but that roughly makes it O(n^2).
If I scale up the processes from 6 to say 1000, O(n^2) will take a huge time.

Is there any standard way of doing such problems - I mean such problems that are easy to visualise - like Gantt charts? Otherwise how do I make this algorithm better, any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid it's just experience, built up from wrestling with similar problems. Hint: The sooner a process *finishes*, the better it is for your purposes.

Comment: I think Wikipedia says that this is a strongly NP-hard problem.

Comment: @Neil: There's an O(n log n) greedy algorithm for solving this optimally. The algorithm itself is simple; what's interesting is why the answer it produces is optimal.

Comment: Is that not homomorphic to the maximum independent vertex set problem?

Comment: @Neil: Are you talking about transforming an IS instance into an instance of this problem by representing vertices with intervals and edges with overlaps? It's not possible to represent every IS instance this way. For example, suppose our IS instance consists of 5 vertices a, b, c, d, e and the edges ab, bc, cd, de. There are 2 ways to represent this: Either with a, c, e being disjoint intervals in that order (and b, d being disjoint intervals in that order), or the mirror image (e, c, a). If we add one more vertex f, and the edges af and ef, there is no way to represent the problem.

Comment: So any cycle subgraph would necessarily need to be fully connected. This constraint makes the problem not equivalent. That makes sense; thank you.

Comment: @Neil: You're welcome :) I think "fully connected" is slightly too strong (it's still possible to represent cycles in which some vertex pairs are not adjacent, e.g., we can represent the non-edges ac and ce in my example), but I don't know how to concisely describe the constraint.

Comment: @j_random_hacker By 'finishes', do you mean the process end time or the process (end time - start time) ?

Comment: Try both. That is, try ordering processes by each of these things, in increasing and then in decreasing order, and looking for a small counterexample to its optimality (3 intervals or fewer).

Answer (score 1):

There are different paths that you could take to find a solution, here are some in no particular order.

- Is that already a solution on the net?

Most likely, important point, Gantt chars are essentially intervals.

- Could it be a graph problem?

Consider that each interval is a node, imaging a start node at 0 (zero) and connect all nodes to all nodes starting later than its end. Use Dijkstra or A* like to find a solution.

- Could it be a dynamic programming problem?

Are there subproblems, yes, add or don't add an interval, repeat.

- Do I know a data structure that is used in this kind of problems?

Yes, [Augmented Interval Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) can it be used for this problem, maybe.